Python adds ending quote to PS auto-completed space-containing directory names
I am passing am trying to pass directories-with-spaces as arguments on windows 11, and using PS autocomplete (TAB) to provide the full name. The '.\a b\' gets naturally completed through powershell, using single-quoted and backslash-escaped, as shown, when building the command and before running the command.
But something adds an ending quotes (") to the argument between the time i press enter, and before my script would run, thus breaking the following argument if i do not trim it.
PS C:\> mkdir "a b"
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        10/08/2024     16:19                a b

PS C:\> python.exe -i '.\a b\'
C:\Users\...\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\a b"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.argv)
['.\\a b"']

Questions : is it normal, and if so, how am i supposed to manage this, besides manually trimming the last quote if present ?

I can only say that I try your example on Mac and result was '.\a b\', that's why I think it is something windows-specific

You're seeing a Windows PowerShell bug that has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7: a string with spaces that ends in \ is incorrectly passed to external programs in that the necessary escaping as \\ in the - of necessity - double-quoted string that is used behind the scenes isn't performed.
See the linked duplicate for details.
